# Change the state of a component on route change - NextJS

Tags: routes, next.js, next-router

I'm trying to change the background on an element on click on a specific route using the `useState` hook. The background of element is changed but it has been changed on the other pages as well. Is there any way that the background of the element can be set back to default on the route change and use the hook on a specific route only ?

Answer (score 3):

For those having the same issue, you can simplily assign new value to key property on the component you are rendering, Next.js will reset the state of that component when the key property changes.

For example:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import YourComponent from 'components/your-compoennt';

export default function YourPage() {
    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        <YourComponent key={router.asPath} />
    )
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next/router` to track when the route has changed. There are probably several ways to achieve what you want. But maybe the cleanest is to simply listen to the route change events:

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents

Or you could track the value of `pathname`. Kind of depends on your needs.